# StatusBarNotification не работает в Андроид 10

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Я использую код для получения уведомлений от яндекснавигатора

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    pack_notif = sbn.getPackageName();
    if (pack_notif.equals("ru.yandex.yandexnavi")) {
        if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
            pack_ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        title_notif = extras.getString("android.title");
        try {
            text_notif = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            text_notif = "";
        }

        try {
            id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

И он работает в Андроид 9, я получаю идентификатор изображения из уведомления в переменной id1, и работаю дальше с ним.
Но в Андроид 10 я получаю id1 равным 0, и не могу получить изображение из уведомления. Хотя я уведомление вижу, и другие данные получаю.
В чём тут загвоздка? Google поменял видать что-то опять.

Эти запросы тоже не работают

```
id2 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON);
id3 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    _icon = sbn.getNotification().getLargeIcon();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     _icon = sbn.getNotification().getSmallIcon();
}
```